# Invalidate Object In Hibernate 2nd Level Cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have an application using Hibernate with ehcache as the 2nd level cache.  I have been trying to figure out how I can invalidate a specific object in the cache thereby forcing hibernate to reload it from the database the next time it is referenced.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried several things but so far been unsuccessful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`SessionFactory.getCache().evictEntity(Class entityClass, Serializable identifier)`

Comment: I've tried this before and had no luck.  Initially when calling `SessionFactory.getCache()` I received a warning about a new cache being created. So, instead I was able to get the correct one via another method and still `evictEntity` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Obviously the first parameter is the class of the entity I want to remove, but what does it want for the second parameter?  Perhaps I've been passing in the wrong thing. Is it the item being used as a key that should be provided?

Comment: It's the value of the @Id for the entity. This is the unique identifier which Hibernate uses as the key in the cache.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that is what I tried before, but I will take another look.

Comment: Well, upon trying this seems to work.  Other than I wasn't able to get the session factory in that way since `SessionFactory` doesn't have a static `getCache()` method. Not sure what was going on with my first try.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that was poor notation. That wasn't meant to imply a static method on SessionFactory.